# Telerik Reports parameters from WindowsForm Codebehind to Report

Tags: winforms, telerik, report, reporting, telerik-reporting

I'm working on a Windows Forms Application where I want to load Reports into a Reportviewer after a click on a Button.
This is the Event that gets triggered by pressing on the button in the Code behind of the Windows Form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new
    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
    reportSource.ReportDocument = new Reportlibrary.Report1();

    reportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("OrderNumber","123456789"));

    reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

}
```

The problem now is that I have no Idea how I can access / get the parameter I added before Refreshing the Reportviewer.
The Report already has set a Datasource. I don't know if this matters.
This is what I have right now. I've tried everything and I'm just not getting further.

```
        public Report1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Position[] all = new Position[]{

               new Position("Test", "Test","test"),

            };

            this.DataSource = all;

             MessageBox.Show("Number: " +
             this.Report.ReportParameters["OrderNumber"].Value.ToString());

        }
```

Is there any way to get this parameter straight after InitializeComponent(); ?
Do I need to add another Event to the report to access it? If yes which on is the best way to do this?

Any help very apreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the parameters of the report on an instance of the report itself (not the report source), such as:

```
        TopPageViews report = new TopPageViews();
        report.ReportParameters["StartDate"].Value = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);
        report.ReportParameters["EndDate"].Value = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);

        InstanceReportSource reportSource = new InstanceReportSource();
        reportSource.ReportDocument = report;

        this.reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

In your report constructor, after InitializeComponent, subscribe a handler to the ItemDataBinding event:

```
    this.ItemDataBinding += TopPageViews_ItemDataBinding;
```

And in your handler, you can obtain the value as you normally would:

```
    DateTime startDateParm = (DateTime)this.ReportParameters["StartDate"].Value;
```

You can use the debugger to see the value.

Answer (score 0):

i know its an old question but after experiencing the same issue this how i did it and passed two parameter of date.

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Report2 report = new Report2();
        report.ReportParameters["datefrom"].Value 
                                 =dateTimePicker1.Value;
        report.ReportParameters["dateto"].Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;

        var rSource = new InstanceReportSource();

        rSource.ReportDocument = report;
        reportViewer1.ReportSource = rSource;
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's best to include context which describes your code and how it solves the OP's problem.  See the following link for community guidelines on code-only answers- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers